# Is there a Socket.IO alternative that is not based on WebSockets?

Tags: socket.io, real-time

I built a realtime application that, thanks to Socket.IO, can serve a lot of different client types (C#, Java, Browser, ...)! I know that there are a lot of Socket.IO alternatives, but from my understanding, everything is more or less based on WebSockets. (I know that Socket.IO has fallbacks if WebSockets are not working, but that they are more less "inferior workarounds" so to speak...)

My question is: Is there any comparable real-time engine available that is NOT based on WebSockets, but can still serve all those different clients?

Comment: Please clarify your question to state what your endpoints are?  Is one endpoint a standards-based browser with no special plug-ins installed?  If so, what versions of IE are you trying to support?  If you aren't talking about a browser on either end of the connection, then your options are limitless as anything that can do TCP has thousands of options, including building your own protocol.

Comment: Why do you post, we ask clarifying questions and you don't even care to answer our questions so we can try to help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what your endpoints are.  If one of the endpoints is a browser with purely the built-in capabilities of the browser and Javascript, then a webSocket is your only way to get a continuous connection from the browser to some other destination.

If a webSocket is not supported (in an older browser), then the other socket.io fallbacks (such as xhr-long-polling) are the next best alternatives.  As the browser has limited communication capabilities, if you can't use a webSocket, then an ajax call is your only other generally supported option without requiring plug-ins on each browser (such as Flash or Java or something like that).  socket.io already supports the next-best options that are available in a browser - you can't do better than that if you're talking about a standard browser with no custom plug-ins.

If your endpoints don't necessarily include a browser and you can use any language or library you want, then you can use plain TCP sockets and then use whatever protocol you want over a TCP socket.

Answer (score 0):

[The WebSocket protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) establishes a bidirectional communication channel between server and client; they kind of speak more naturally with each other. The server can just send something to the client and the other way around. In http it just goes in one direction, there's a request and a response and everything needs to be initiated with a request from the client.

From my experience, realtime webApps like a multiplayer game or a chat become easier to develop and it apparently creates less overhead than using http - but still you can do the same things more or less elegant with http as well (see e.g. [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology)).
Look at gmail or other existing webApps, they all use http (so does Socket.io as a fallback) and it works quite well.